# Could not collect Heart rate at the end of a fitness task from ios ResearchKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-watch, researchkit

I wear an Apple Watch, which collects my heart rate periodically and sends it to the Health App in my iPhone.

Now I have created a Fitness task (code below) and trying to read the heartrate of the user's activity. but could not. It says *Error No collected data was found. in Recorder: heartRate*

```
    ORKOrderedTask *fitnessTask = [ORKOrderedTask fitnessCheckTaskWithIdentifier:@"FitnessTask"
                                                      intendedUseDescription:@"Intended Use"
                                                                walkDuration:6*60
                                                                restDuration:3*60
                                                                     options:ORKPredefinedTaskOptionNone];
```

The Results recorded Pedometer, Accelerometer and Device motion... But How can I read the heart rate of the user?

Do I have to do any set up with the Apple watch as well before the task is started? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Apple Watch doesn't stream heart rate to HealthKit on the phone, you need to find a BTLE heart rate strap and connect it directly to the phone via `settings->Bluetooth`. And make sure you can see the real time heart rate showing up in Health app. Then ResearchKit can collect heart rate during the task.